# Check and Change owner recursively with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, access-control-list

I know that I have seen how to change the owner but I was wondering if there was a way to check it first and only set it if it needs changed?

The current command I have to change it is:
dir -r c:\Users\goyuix\temp | set-acl -aclobject $acl1

I want to check it first to try and speed things up on a large folder.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the objet is in the ACL, so you can read it like that:

```
$owner=(get-acl c:\temp).Owner
```

Comment: So how can I use that to check before applying the permissions?

Comment: I have tried something like this... takeown /F "G:\Folder1" /A /R /D Y | Where-Object {(Get-Acl $_.Fullname).Owner -isnot "Domain1\user"}